# Autocomplete- remote json source - multidimensional

Tags: jquery, json, autocomplete

This is my remote JSON file source for my autocomplete box.

```js
{
  "country": [{
    "name": "Spain",
    "city": [{
      "code": "BCN",
      "name": "Barcelona",
      "location": [{
        name": "Barcelona Downtown",
        "airportCode": "BCN"
      }, {
        "name": "The Barceloneta",
        "airportCode": "BCN"
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Norway",
    "city": [{
      "code": "OSLALL",
      "name": "Oslo",
      "location": [{
        "name": "Oslo Downtown",
        "airportCode": "OSL"
      }, {
        "name": "Fornebu",
        "airportCode": "OSL"
      }, {
        "name": "Lysaker",
        "airportCode": "TRF"
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "France",
    "city": [{
      "code": "PARALL",
      "name": "Paris",
      "location": [{
        ", "name": "Paris Downtown",
        "airportCode": "ORY"
      }, {
        "name": "The Touquet-Paris-Plage",
        "airportCode": "ORY"
      }, {
        "name": "The Arcs",
        "airportCode": "ORY"
      }]
    }]
  }]
}
```

When an item is selected in autocomplete form I want to save airportcode in a hidden field. Please help me on this.

If you have some better idea to read data from this Json and get the same functionality, that would be great.

Comment: Your JSON is malformed. You're missing a `"` before the `name": "Barcelona Downtown` property and you've got a random extra `","` before `Paris Downtown`

Comment: thank you.Could you add this javascript also here, I'm not able to add.
This is my javascript.
$("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
source: function(request, response) {
$.ajax({  url: "",success: function(data) {
var search_data = [];$(data.country).each(function(index, value) {
$(value.city).each(function(index, value) {
$(value.location).each(function(index, value) {
if ((value.name).indexOf(request.term) != -1) {
search_data.push(value.name);
}})})})response(search_data);
}});},
select: function(event, ui) {
$("#autocompleteHidden").val(ui.item.airportCode);
};

Comment: You are able to add it - click the `edit` link under the question.

Comment: I tried to add, but it says some format issue. I'm not sure about that. Pls help